# Convert Text File into List and Access elements of List using Index

Tags: java, string, list, loops, file

I try several times to convert the text in a File into List and print some elements of the List according to reference index but I can't, it throws Index Out Of Bounds Exception: index 3 , Size 1

is there any possible way to overcome the situation.

myTEXT.txt

```
PETTY MIND,2023,IS,COMMING
```

my Code

```
List<String> TexttoList = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    FileReader myTEXT = new FileReader("myTEXT.txt");
    
    Scanner scanText = new Scanner(myTEXT);
    scanText.useDelimiter(",\\s*");
    
    while(scanText.hasNext()) {
        
        
        for(int d = 0; d<4; d++){
        TexttoList.add(d , scanText.next());
        System.out.println(TexttoList.get(3));
        //IndexOutOfBounds Exception: index 3 , Size 1
        }
    }
```

it only prints First index(0) and return the entire text

```
    PETTY MIND
    2023
    IS
    COMMING
```

Comment: Hello. What is `myTEXT` in `new Scanner(myTEXT);`? Note that `FileReader` which is set to read from `myTEXT.txt` file is named `FileReader scores`. Please use [edit] option and clarify/correct your question so we wouldn't waste your (and our) time on unrelated problems.

Comment: Anyway regarding `IndexOutOfBounds Exception: index 3 , Size 1` please carefully read your for loop. Note that in its first iteration you are adding *one* element to `TexttoList`, but immediately after that, you are trying to read value from position 3, which *doesn't exist* yet. Maybe you wanted to read it *after* your loop finished reading all data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the NIO API

Java NIO (New IO) is an alternative IO API for Java

```java
var list = Files.readString(Paths.get("myText.txt")).split(",\\s*");
```

Code explanation:

- Files.readString()

> Reads all content from a file into a string, decoding from bytes to characters using the UTF-8 charset. The method ensures that the file is closed when all content have been read or an I/O error, or other runtime exception, is thrown.

- Paths.get()

> Converts a path string, or a sequence of strings that when joined form a path string, to a Path

- split(): split the content of the file (the returned string from the method `Files.readString`) and returns array of string.